# Rails DirectUploadsController: override #create method to add custom headers values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I wonder if it is possible to override `DirectUploadsController#create` method that [calls](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f33d52c95217212cbacc8d5e44b5a8e3cdc6f5b3/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/direct_uploads_controller.rb#L7) a private `direct_upload_json` method:

```rb
class ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController < ActiveStorage::BaseController
  def create
    blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!(blob_args)
    render json: direct_upload_json(blob)
  end

private
...
def direct_upload_json(blob)
  blob.as_json(root: false, methods: :signed_id).merge(direct_upload: {
    url: blob.service_url_for_direct_upload,
    headers: blob.service_headers_for_direct_upload
  })
end
```

I need it to set a `Authorization Bearer <token>` as well another key/value to the request header.
Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  post '/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads', to: 'image_uploads#create'
end
```

override your `DirectUploadsController`

```
#app/controllerss/image_uploads_controler.rb  
class ImageUploadsController < ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController

  def create
    super
  end

  private

  def direct_upload_json(blob)
    headers = blob.service_headers_for_direct_upload
    headers[:custom_header] = "TEST HEADER"
    blob.as_json(root: false, methods: :signed_id).merge(direct_upload: {
      url: blob.service_url_for_direct_upload,
      headers: headers
    })
  end
end
```